# Can't import uxtheme library

Tags: c, winapi, tdm-gcc, uxtheme

I want to import `uxtheme` to my c program and use some variable types that are in `uxtheme.h` library.
When I use this and compile my project, my computer shows me some unreasonable error. Like this:

> unknown type name 'DTTOPTS'

But I am sure that `DTTOPTS` is defined in `uxtheme.h`.

Why my PC shows me this error and how I can resolve it?

My Codes:

```
#include <studio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
int main(){
    DTTOPTS d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When creating a [mcve], please make sure it doesn't contain any other unrelated errors. And especially don't rewrite it into the question, copy-paste it instead. That way you don't add typos (like your code have). Also please include the *full* and *complete* output of the build in the question, as there might be informational notes that contain hints about the problem. Lastly please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Try visual studio.

Comment: Is `studio.h`  a typo which means `stdio.h`? if so, it works for me with sdk version 10.0.18362.0

Answer (score 1):

The [DTTOPTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/ns-uxtheme-dttopts) structure is conditionally defined, if the target OS is set to Windows Vista (or later). [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers) explains, which preprocessor symbols need to be defined.

You can `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600` in your code (prior to including Windows SDK header files) to make the structure visible to the compiler. Ideally, you would set the preprocessor symbol on the command line, e.g. `/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600`, so that all your code gets to agree on the same target version.